# Saving data from two containerviews

Tags: swift, ios8, container-view

First of all i wanne apologize for the code that will be used. I'am completely new to programming in general and it probably looks like .... :)

My problem is the following;

I have 1 ViewController (VC1) with 2 embedded container views (both TableViewControllers). Causs of the UI layout i want for my app i couldn't just use 1 TableVieController. Both of these container views have Textfields, labels, pickerviews that needs to be provided with data by the user. 
Now i want to save all this data with 1 button from the VC1.

Everything displays without error but when i tap the save button is gives me the following error: 
**Could not cast value of type AddRaptorTableVCContainerOne' (0x1099ad840) to AddRaptorTableVCContainerTwo' (0x1099ad270).**

Thanks in advance!

```
@IBAction func addRaptorSaveButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Reference to childViewController

    let childViewOne = childViewControllers.last as! AddRaptorTableVCContainerOne

    let childViewTwo = childViewControllers.last as! AddRaptorTableVCContainerTwo


    // Reference moc
    let manObjCon = self.manObjCon
    let addRaptorEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AddRaptorEntity", inManagedObjectContext: manObjCon!)

    // Create instance of data model and initialize

    var newRaptor = AddRaptorEntity(entity: addRaptorEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: manObjCon)

    // Map our properties

    newRaptor.image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.addImageView.image, 1)
    newRaptor.name = childViewOne.nameTextField.text
    newRaptor.ringNo = childViewTwo.ringNoInputTextField.text


    // Save our context

    var error: NSError?

    manObjCon!.save(nil)
    println(newRaptor)
```

Answer (score 0):

In two lines, you're saying that `childViewControllers.last` is two different things.  Check whats actually in `childViewControllers`, using the debugger or by printing, and pick the right thing to cast as `AddRaptorTableVCContainerTwo`.

Comment: (+1) Thank you i overlooked that double .last. Even i triple- checked everything! // Cause i'am new on this i can't display the +1